# Java performance problem for math.abs

Tags: java, performance, math, data-structures, matrix

I am using [Jama matrix](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) to perform SVD operations. I have couple of questions regarding performance.

I am not worried about so much accuracy, and I think double is more accurate than Float, am I right? If I use float other than double, how much will it improve the performance and reduce accuracy?

In Jama matrix it uses one function that it calls a lot, it used double and Math.abs function, that requires a lot of Heap and CPU. If I change it to double and remove Math.abs, how much will it impact the performance and results in terms of accuracy?

Here is the Jama math function:

```
   public static double hypot(double a, double b) {
      double r;
      if (Math.abs(a) > Math.abs(b)) {
         r = b/a;
         r = Math.abs(a)*Math.sqrt(1+r*r);
      } else if (b != 0) {
         r = a/b;
         r = Math.abs(b)*Math.sqrt(1+r*r);
      } else {
         r = 0.0;
      }
      return r;
   }
```

Here is the what I am thinking to do with this function

```
   public static float hypot(float a, float b) {
      float r;
      if (a > b) {
         r = b/a;
         r = (float) (a*Math.sqrt(1+r*r));
      } else if (b != 0) {
         r = a/b;
         r = (float) (b*Math.sqrt(1+r*r));
      } else {
         r = 0;
      }
      return r;
   }
```

I do not know, if it is a good way to do it or not.
Thanks

Comment: I dont see how a single Math.abs method can use any heap at all?

Comment: Jama calls Math.abs so frequently and if you have big Matrix then it will kill your system :( There would be millions calls for Math.abs then ...

Comment: So you're confident that this method will never be called with negative operands?  Anyway I would be surprised if you got much of a speed boost with what you're trying, particularly on a 64-bit VM.  But try it, not worrying about precision for now, and see how much difference it will actually make.  Only you can know that; we don't have your code to know whether it will make a positive difference.

Comment: @user289333 - calling a function millions of times uses the same small stack space millions of times, and no heap space at all. (You are right about the overhead in CPU time for all those calls. It seems somewhat ridiculous for a matrix math library to be coded that way.)

Comment: You might want to explore some branchless alternatives for these functions.  At the beginning I would use a non-branching `max` to assign a to the absolutely larger value and b to the smaller, and then eliminate the ifs if possible.

Comment: @Mark: What does a "non-branching max" look like in Java?

Comment: @Gabe:  `a - ((a-b) & ((a-b) >> 31))`, according to http://www.coranac.com/documents/bittrick/ (I'm assuming if "accuracy isn't important" one can instead use an integer intermediary).  But they note there that it's probably not of much, if any, gain because the gains from not having a branch probably are lost in the extra instructions.  TBH I'm not sure why I posted that suggestion, though I was also thinking `abs`.  As you say in you answer the branching is mostly there for some special cases anyways.

Comment: The sqrt) function is by far the most expensive operation here. Much more than abs().

Comment: @Mark: It's probably safe to assume that an integer is not sufficiently precise.

Comment: @Gabe: Why not?  You can just use an integer, store the scale in another integer, and then scale back to a float afterward (e.g. if your operands are 1.234 and 5.678, do it on 1234 and 5678 and store a scale of 1000).  I don't think you're losing much precision really.

Comment: @Mark: I don't think that emulating floating point is going to speed up anything.

Answer (score 6):

I would expect a good JIT to inline a `Math.abs` call to just a single instruction. If your code is running on an FPU (quite likely), using `float` will not gain you any speed because nearly all FPUs are 64-bit or better.

However, the reason that the algorithm is so unusual is that it prevents overflow when the magnitude of its operands are on the order of 10^150. If you are considering using `float`, your operands must not be of magnitude larger than around 10^38, meaning that the fastest algorithm will just be:

```
public static double hypot(double a, double b) {
    return Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
}
```

Comment: If you look at the source for Math, you'll see that abs(float) is not going to be in-lined as a single instruction. It calls `Float.floatToIntBits`, zeroes the sign bit, then calls `Float.intBitsToFloat`. The two `Float` methods, in turn, are native methods (that probably just return the passed value). Assuming everything is in-lined, this becomes three instructions with no branching. (Kind of slick, actually.)

Comment: Ted: It's possible for a JIT compiler to have a special case for many library functions, the same way that a C compiler will have special cases for things like `fabs` and `strcpy` to turn them into single instructions (or thereabouts).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will not work for negative arguments. Just add:

```
if (a < 0) a = -a;
if (b < 0) b = -b;
```

at the start of your function and all should be well. (By "not work" I mean that it will not always do the calculation in a way that minimizes rounding errors and risk of overflow.)

Comment: It might actually be faster to use `a = Math.abs(a)` instead of using an `if` because the `abs` could get optimized to a single instruction, while an `if` requires a branch that's hard to predict.

Comment: @Gabe - Really? What single instruction would that be? There's nothing like an `fabs` among the [Java bytecodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings).

Comment: @TedHopp This makes something absolute `((x >> 30) | 1) * x`, I guess JIT can do things like that.

Comment: @clankill3r - Yes, that will work. (But shouldn't it be `x >> 31`?) It also doesn't have any branching, which plays nicely with instruction pipelines. On the other hand, it always does two bit operations and a multiply. My code does a sign test and branches but doesn't do any math operations unless the argument is negative. I have no idea which approach performs better; I suppose it depends on the distribution of values and on how much of a performance hit there is for branching.